# How to include a method in a Rails seed:db file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activemodel

I have the following Rail5 seeds.rb file:

s1-s4 are created above.

```
job_titles = JobTitle.all
job_titles.each_with_index do |job_title, index|
  case job_title.title
  when "XXXX"
    self.create_job_title_skills([s1,s2,s3,s4])
  end
end

def create_job_title_skills(items)    
  puts "create_job_title_skills"
  items.each do |skill|
    puts skill
  end    
end
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `create_job_title_skills' for main:Object
```

I only need this method for the seed file, how can I get a method to work in a Rails 5 seeds.rb file only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the method **before** you call it, like this:

```
def create_job_title_skills(items)    
  puts "create_job_title_skills"
  items.each do |skill|
    puts skill
  end    
end

job_titles = JobTitle.all
job_titles.each_with_index do |job_title, index|
  case job_title.title
  when "XXXX"
    self.create_job_title_skills([s1,s2,s3,s4])
  end
end
```